# Paramiko exec_command times out lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, paramiko

I am running into a problem with paramiko on AWS lambda where my function times out when the ssh function is called. Strangely, this timeout only happens intermittently. When I change the command to, for example, PWD, then back to the command in the snippet below, the function returns what is expected from the command. Furthermore, this code when testing on my local machine works fine.

My lambda function is in the right VPCs and security groups within AWS to ssh into the host and the lambda does not exceed the memory allocated to it.

Is the problem something obvious that I am missing? Please help!

my code

```
class fileFinder:

    _uname = None
    _password = None

    def __init__(self, secret, params) -> None:
        self._uname = secret["uname"]
        self._password = secret["password"]
        self.params=params
    

    def ssh(self):
        
        try:
            client = SSHClient()
            
            client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
            
            client.connect(hostname="myhost", username=self._uname, password=self._password)

            stdin, stdout, stderr  = client.exec_command(' cd /my/cool/pathway; find ./ -name "PREFIX*.hst"  -newerct "2023-09-01T00:00" -not -newerct "2023-10-01T11:09"')
            output = stdout.read().decode("utf8")

            return self.buildResponse(output)
        except Exception as error:
            print("there was an error" + repr(error))

        
    def buildResponse(self, stdout)  :
        
        
        fileList: list[str] = []

        currFname: str = ""

        for i in range(len(stdout)):
            if stdout[i] == "." and stdout[i+1] == "/" or stdout[i] ==  "/" :
                continue
            elif stdout[i] == "\n":
                fileList.append(currFname)
                currFname = ""
            else:
                currFname += stdout[i]    
        
        return {"logs" : fileList}
```

failure code

```
{
  "errorMessage": "2023-10-02T18:14:32.828Z 7b520d57-bc32-49b6-8da7-653c24a1bfe5 Task timed out after 20.02 seconds"
}
```

Comment: The issue seems to be related to the subnets my lambda has access to. I enrolled the function into a number of subnets that turned out not to be necessary. Once only the necessary subnets were enrolled the hanging ceased

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to send an empty packet to keep the connection alive.
Add `client.get_transport().set_keepalive(60)` after connecting. This send an empty packet to keep the connection alive for every 60 seconds